# Cannot access a folder without using the port

Tags: apache-2.2

I have created a new folder inside already existed folder in my application.
When I use the port and access this folder it is working fine. But without the port it cannot be accessed.

Ex :

ip:port/sample/newFolder/sample-1.js --> can be accessed

ip/sample/newFolder/sample-1.js      --> 404 error

But there was another folder in the same path and the js files inside that can be accessed.

Ex :

ip:port/sample/existedFolder/sample-1.js --> can be accessed

ip/sample/existedFolder/sample-1.js      --> can be accessed

Can anyone please help me how can I access js files inside the newFolder.

Comment: The 'port' is not 80?

Comment: I'm using two nodes. 8180 for node1 and 8280 for node 2
I also use a loadblancer(HAProxy) to redirect the traffic.
But the thing is I can access folders that are created earlier and can't access js files in new folder.

Comment: Well, you are accessing different application when you add the port. Without the port, you probably hit the LB which points to server/app that does not have new folder added. Check HAProxy configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing different application when you add the port. Without the port, you probably hit the LB which points to server/app that does not have new folder added. Check HAProxy configuration.